# I am trying to read the Output from the Openfiles.exe and this is not working

Tags: vb.net, process

This is to run the openfiles.exe and return the output from it
If i run openfiles.exe at the command line it works as expected
When I run it here there is no error but i get nothing in the Messagebox

```
Dim NewProcess As New Process()
    With NewProcess.StartInfo
        .FileName = "openfiles.exe"
        .Arguments = "/query /s FakeServer/fo csv /V /U FakeDomain\Fakeuser/P pword"
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        .CreateNoWindow = False
    End With

    NewProcess.Start()

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

    MsgBox(NewProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd)
```

Comment: Some applications (for instance FFmpeg) write to the error stream rather than the output stream. Have you tried `MsgBox(NewProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd())` as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample code that I have that is similar to what you are trying to do. However, my app was trying to run a command using cmd.exe and display the result in real time to a textbox. You can try to modify it accordingly.

```
Dim cmd As New Process()
Dim strCommandLine As String = "Echo Hello World"

cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = True
Application.DoEvents()

AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf OutputHandler
AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf OutputHandler

cmd.Start()

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCommandLine)
cmd.StandardInput.Flush()
cmd.StandardInput.Close()
cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
cmd.Close()

Delegate Sub UpdateTextBoxDelg(text As String)
Public myDelegate As UpdateTextBoxDelg = New UpdateTextBoxDelg(AddressOf UpdateTextBox)

Public Sub UpdateTextBox(text As String)
    txtOutput.Text += text & Environment.NewLine
    txtOutput.SelectionStart = txtOutput.Text.Length
    txtOutput.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub

Private Sub OutputHandler(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Me.Invoke(myDelegate, e.Data)
    Else
        UpdateTextBox(e.Data)
    End If
End Sub
```